# Rock Paper scissors game-python

Tags: python

I'm currently in the process of making a game like rock-paper-scissors. For this, I was thinking about using the randint() function to generate random numbers. But I want to make it better, so that the program remembers the players past choice history and plays against it. How could I do this? I'm a beginner, but i'm ready to learn if pointed in the right way.

I've tried using the concept of conditional probability over the top of my head, so far it hasn't been working as expected.

```
def probable(model,test_model):
    p={}
    for i in 'rps':
        check_sequence=test_model+i
        if model.count(test_model)==0:
            return -1
        p[i]=(model.count(check_sequence)/model.count(test_model))
    if p[max(p)]==0:
        return -1
    else:
        return max(p)
```

Here the variable "test_model" contains the past the choices made by the player. Variable "Model" contains the entire list of choices made by the user.

Comment: As you are learning, I would not try packages. Here's a first idea: For each play add the other two alternatives to a (python) list. Then grab a random element out of that list. For the first move (empty list) do a random reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use simply arrays for this problem. For example, if you declare an array for all random choices like

```
choices = ['r', 's', 'p']
```

and if you random integer in between 0 and len(choices), it will choose one of them. And if you want to remember the past choices, you can simple add/delete each choice to the array. For example, if player plays 'r', you can add 'p' to choices and it's probability to be chosen will increase.

```
choices.append('p')
```

Now your choices array is something like this

```
['r', 's', 'p', 'p']
```

But at each time you need to check whether there is at least one of 'r', 's' and 'p' in array. Also if you add consequtively the same choice to this array, it is going to likely to pick last added one. So you may need the adjust prob array.

Here is my solution:

```
import random

probs = ['r', 's', 'p']
opposites = {'r':'p', 'p':'s', 's':'r'}
beats = {'r':'s', 'p':'r', 's':'p'}

def controlProbs():
    if 'r' not in probs:
        probs.append('r')
    if 's' not in probs:
        probs.append('s')
    if 'p' not in probs:
        probs.append('p')

def adjustProbs(choice):
    if len(probs) > 20:
        probs.remove(choice)
        controlProbs()
    else:
        probs.append(beats[choice])

def pick():
    index = random.randint(0, len(probs)-1)
    return probs[index]

def controlInput(player):
    if len(player) != 1 or player not in 'rsp':
        return False
    return True

while True:
    player = raw_input("Pick your equipment!: ")
    if not controlInput:
        print "Please choose a valid one! (r, s, p)"
        continue
    computer = pick()
    print "My choice is: " + computer
    if opposites[player] == computer:
        print "You beat me!"
    elif opposites[computer] == player:
        print "I beat you!"
    else:
        print "Tie :)"

    #Here is adjusting probobalities
    adjustProbs(player)
```

And for this solution you get that output:

```
Pick your equipment!: r
My choice is: p
You beat me!
Pick your equipment!: r
My choice is: p
You beat me!
Pick your equipment!: r
My choice is: p
You beat me!
Pick your equipment!: r
My choice is: p
You beat me!
Pick your equipment!: r
My choice is: s
I beat you!
Pick your equipment!: r
My choice is: s
I beat you!
Pick your equipment!: r
My choice is: s
I beat you!
Pick your equipment!:
```

Hope my answer is understandable!

*Note: My solution surely can be upgraded. It is not the best one but easy one.*

Comment: Nice solution; you could make it more efficient by maintaining just counts of rock,paper & scissors and sample from that distribution. Some nice approaches to sampling from a distribution: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/

Comment: @VikasMenon Thanks! Would machine learning techniques be far fetched?